# Find out which program is starting and stopping within a second

Tags: windows-10

On my laptop, about every half hour, a window pops up and closes again very quickly.

I think it is a program that starts and stops really fast. I want to know which program that is.

Is there a way to find out which program is starting and stopping?

Already looked in the task scheduler, registry run and run once but did not find anything.

Also looked in the event viewer, but cannot find anything or I'm searching in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) (a Microsoft Sysinternals tool) can be set up to keep "dead" processes in its list for an amount of time, thus giving you a chance to see what it is that is appearing and disappearing.

From this [handy guide from Kansas State University](https://www.k-state.edu/its/security/training/2009-4-9/presentations/handouts/Process_Explorer_Tutorial_Handout.pdf)

> Difference Highlight Duration: this dialog allows you to configure the duration of time that new processes show in green **and ones that have exited show in red**. The default is one second. You can change the highlighting colors by editing them in the Configure Highlighting dialog that you open in the Options menu.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Office installed? If so it's probably the OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerRegistration task. But IME that one runs once an hour.

If you have Windows 10 Professional, use gpedit.msc to enable event logging for process start and end. (Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Local Policies | Audit Policy , then enable "success" in "Audit process tracking".)

Then after you see the window open and close, wait a few minutes and then look in Event Viewer (in Windows Logs | Security).

If you can't run gpedit.msc, Process Monitor from sysinternals.com may be helpful.